# Как убрать из sql-запроса ячейки, содержащие определённое значение?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем привет!

Реализую список вывода друзей на сайте.

Таблица в БД такая:

```
|  id   |  user_one | user_two | status |
   1        44          45          1
```

В итоге я зaхожу под своим логином с id = 44, и sql 
Запрос получает все строки, где встречается 44:

```
user_one = 44 OR user_two = 44
```

Проблема в том, что 44 может быть как в первой, так и во второй колонке.

Соответственно вопрос: как мне правильно составить запрос, чтобы возвращалась только 1 ячейка, которая была бы не равна 44?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант номер раз:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN `user_one` = 44  THEN `user_two` ELSE `user_one` END) AS `friend`
FROM 
  `friends` 
WHERE `user_one` = 44 OR `user_two` = 44;
```

Вариант номер два (при наличии индексов будет работать очень быстро):

```
SELECT `user_one` AS `friend`
FROM `friends` 
WHERE `user_two` = 44
  UNION ALL    
SELECT `user_two` AS `friend`
FROM `friends` 
WHERE `user_one` = 44;
```

Вариант три - зеркалить записи:

```
44 | 45 | 1
45 | 44 | 1
```

P.S. Зачем вам поле id? Пара(`user_one`, `user_two`) - уникальна, и можно её сделать ключом, а id убрать. Кстати, в любом случае вам желательно сделать эту пару уникальным ключиком. Тогда проще будет добавлять или апдейтить записи, не опасаясь дубликатов.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил это так:

    SELECT status, IF(user_one = 44,user_two,user_one) AS user FROM partners WHERE user_one = 44 OR user_two = 44;
____
@Deonis, По поводу уникальных ключей щас попробую, думал об этом. А разве когда столбец делается уникальным, туда можно добавлять: uni 44 | 45 44 | 46 ? Он пропустит? или когда делаешь 2 уникальных поля, то система смотрит чтобы именно эти два в паре были уникальны?

Comment: @chuikoff, составной уникальный ключ:

    ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`user_one`,`user_two`);

Теперь можно использовать или "INSERT IGNORE" или "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".